# Build same same web for different ccTLD

Tags: web-applications, meteor

I am building a webapp with Meteor.

My webapp will have same UI (and pages) in different languages. It will be localized and deployed over different ccTLDs (.cz, .sk, .hu, .tr, ... .com).

Here is similar case of what I want. It is a [czech parfums eshop](http://www.parfums.cz/). When you scroll down bottom, there are flags (links) to different domains.

My webapp can be broken down into this pieces:

- [DB] Database can be same for many languages.
- [common-code] Most of the code is same between different languages
- [routing & i18n] Different parts for every languages is routing file and i18n file(s)

There should be some way how to build/run/debug an app with different routing file and i18n file(s).

I don't want to have one .com domain and be able to switch languages. [Why?](http://jirikrepl.com/2015/07/20/seo-notes/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using one code base with internationalization files.  You can use the tap-i18n package (https://github.com/TAPevents/tap-i18n) for this along with iron-router and the iron-router-i18n package (https://github.com/yoolab/iron-router-i18n).  For example:

```
meteor create intl
meteor add tap:i18n
meteor add iron:router
meteor add martino:iron-router-i18n
```

This creates a basic project for demonstration purposes and adds the tap-i18n, iron-router, and iron-router-i18n packages.

Let's assume we want to support English, Spanish, and French.  Create an i18n directory to store your internationalization files.  The files contain the text strings that are translated for the various versions of the site (sorry if my translations are not perfect):

i18n/en.i18n.json:

```
{
        "settings": "settings",
        "home": "home",
        "welcome text": "Welcome to Meteor!",
        "home text": "This is the home page.",
        "settings text": "On this page you can modify settings."
}
```

i18n/es.i18n.json:

```
{
        "settings": "configuracion",
        "home": "inicial",
        "welcome text": "Bienvenido a Meteoro!",
        "home text": "Esta es la pagina de inicio.",
        "settings text": "En esta pagina usted puede modificar la configuracion."
}
```

i18n/fr.i18n.json:

```
{
        "settings": "parametres",
        "home": "premiere",
        "welcome text": "Bienvenue au Meteor!",
        "home text": "Cette page est la page d'accueil.",
        "settings text": "Sur cette page vous pouvez modifier les parametres."
}
```

Note that the file names start with the language code (en, es, fr).  I'm using the code list from http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry, but the code doesn't really matter as you correctly reference it later in the iron-router-i18n configuration.

Now create a settings.json file for your application to specify the language that you want to use for the current deployment.  Here I'm using 'es' for Spanish (again, this must match the prefix used above for your i18n file):

settings.json:

```
{
  "public": {
    "i18nLanguageCode": "es"
  }
}
```

**This is the one and only file that will need to be modified for each deployment.**

On startup of theapplication, we call the TAPi18n setLanguage function, passing in the value from the settings.json file, and I'll register a global template helper to get the current language:

intl.js:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  TAPi18n.setLanguage(Meteor.settings.public.i18nLanguageCode);

  Template.registerHelper("getCurrentLanguage", function(){
    return Meteor.settings.public.i18nLanguageCode;
  });

}
```

Here is the intl.html file:

```
<template name="layout">
  <h1>{{_ "welcome text"}}</h1>

  {{> yield}}
</template>

<template name="home">
  <p>{{_ "home text"}}</p>
  <p><a href="{{pathFor route='settings' lang=getCurrentLanguage}}">{{_ "settings"}}</a></p>
</template>

<template name="settings">
  <p>{{_ "settings text"}}</p>
  <p><a href="{{pathFor route='home' lang='en'}}">{{_ "home"}}</a></p>
</template>
```

Notice the helper provided by the tap-i18n package (the underscore followed by the string in quotes).  These placeholders ("welcome text", "home text", "settings text", "settings", "home") get replaced by the proper translation text from the i18n files that we created.  The `getCurrentLanguage` function passes the current language code to the iron-router-i18n pathFor helper.

Now let's create the router configuration.

router.js:

```
I18NConf.configure({
  defaultLanguage: 'en',
  languages: [Meteor.settings.public.i18nLanguageCode],
  autoConfLanguage: true
});

Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  i18n: {
    compulsoryLangCode: false,
    langCodeForDefaultLanguage: false,
    addLangCode: function(url){
      return url;
    },
    langCodeAction: function(path){
      /* by default Router.setLanguage would be called and we do not want that */
    }
  }
});

Router.route('/', function() {
  this.render('home');
}, {
  name: 'home'
});

Router.route('settings', function() {
  this.render('settings');
}, {
  i18n: {
    languages: {
      es: { path: '/ajustes' },
      fr: { path: '/parametres'}
    }
  }
});
```

Notice that I'm passing `Meteor.settings.public.i18nLanguageCode` into `I18NConf.configure`, and that for each route that you want a translated path, you need to add the configuration:

```
  i18n: {
    languages: {
      es: { path: '/ajustes' },
      fr: { path: '/parametres'}
    }
  }
```

When you run meteor, run it using the settings file:

```
meteor run --settings settings.json
```

I've created a sample repo here: https://github.com/markleiber/intl

Comment: Great answer, but what about routing?

Comment: @Jirik: answer updated to explain routing.  I also added a repo on github with the code.